# Need help w/ Powershell loop & execute - simple issue?

Tags: powershell

I have a basic text file with lines of information.  Each line is a requested file to open.

I want a simple script to loop each line, opening each file until the document is empty.

For example

`images.txt` contains:

```
pic1.jpg
pic2.jpg
pic3.jpg
pic4.jpg
```

I've tried creating an array and can get the information to `echo` correctly, but having issues setting up a basic loop and having it stop when there are no more lines!

I've had some coding experience before but I'm pretty new to PS!  Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: PLEASE, post your code in your Question so that we can discuss it.

Comment: I'm having trouble setting up the loop and necessary options to delete lines after opening.

$file_data = Get-Content *.txt

echo $file_data[2] (works)
echo $file_data[3]
echo $file_data[6]

Invoke-Expression -Command "PathToFiles\$file_data[1]"

So I'm able to read the file and store it into an array, echo each line and it shows the correct values, but using a few methods to count/delete a line has been confusing to me =/

Comment: @JV I closed this against a duplicate target that shows how to loop through the lines - but you need to think slightly differently about "removing lines" from a file than when you're editing it in a text editor - you don't "remove a line" from a file, instead, you read the file and then you write back everything _except_ for the lines you want to remove

Comment: foreach($line in Get-Content .\runme.txt) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        Invoke-Expression -Command "pathtofiles\$line"
    }
}

This appears to be opening the files that match which is what I wanted, and it's even acting as a loop in reading the entire contents of the text file so it *should* work :P

Thanks guys

Comment: @JV - glad to know that you got it working! [*grin*] **_however,_** next time, _please add your code to the Question, not in a comment. the 2nd is quite hard to read ...